# Number of occurence of a name in list

Tags: python, string, list, split

Here is my homework:

> Write a function, number of occurrences(string, name) which returns the number of occurrences of name in the string of names string.
>
> For example, number of occurrences('Alojz, Samo, Peter, Alojz, Franci','Alojz') should return 2.

Here is my solution:

```
def number_of_occurence(string,name):
    m = 0
    l = string.split(',')
    for i in l:
        if i == name:
            m+=1
    return m
```

This gives wrong answer because it doesn't check every element of a list. Can someone please help to find mistake?

Answer (score 1):

you can use collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
l = (word.strip() for word in string.split(','))
c = Counter(l)
return c[name]
```

edited

OR

You can use regex:

```
def count_naem(string, name):
    return len(re.findall("{},".format(name), string+","))
```

Comment: That of course doesn't work, because you didn't even try to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your input string to `('Alojz,Samo,Peter,Alojz,Franci' , 'Alojz')` from `('Alojz, Samo, Peter, Alojz, Franci' , 'Alojz')`, it would work.

You need to remove extra spaces from input string.

OR

Replace white space from string.

```
    def number_of_occurrences(string,name):
    m = 0
    string = string.replace(" ", "")
    l = string.split(',')
    for i in l:

        if i == name:           
            m+=1
    return m
```

Comment: Added another solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can just trim out whitespaces after splitting the string.

use `strip()` to strip `whitespaces` from both sides. you can have `whitespaces` in both sides.

this may help you:

```
def number_of_occurence(string,name):
    m = 0
    l = string.split(',')
    for i in l:
        if i.strip() == name:
            m+=1
    return m
```

If you have `tabs \t` ,`newline \n` or `escape sequence \r` in your string, then you can use `strip(' \t\n\r)` instead of `strip()`.